# Call a method in specific time even if app is killed

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

I am developing an app which only works in 8.30am to 5.30pm. I want to store the data only in between 8.30am to 5.30 pm. I used local notification for doing so. But it only works when user tap the notification.In 8.30am and 5.30pm, i need to execute some code even if the app is killed. Is there any other mechanism to do so...?

Here is my code:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (notification!=nil)
{
    [self application:application didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
     code to be executed;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use the silent push notification for this requirement.

Comment: my main problem is Didlaunch method is not called when a notification comes in background.

Comment: have you use silent push notification?

Comment: nope! Can we do it with local notification..?

Comment: No you can't do it with a local notification, and silent push notifications are very unreliable in terms of what time they get delivered to the app (huge delays compared to non-silent push), also if he user force quits an app a silent push is never delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to execute a method in your app if the app is killed. You can bring the app up in the background using silent notifications. But silent notifications are better suited for News apps or apps which need to download content in the background so it is readily available for users when the app comes to the foreground.

Apart from this, the only way to execute the method is when it is either in the foreground or at least active in the background (using one of the available background modes). If your app is using a background mode only to stay in the background, Apple will reject the app, so be careful.

Comment: And I'm so grateful that apps cannot start themselves and run arbitrary code in the background.